# bind messages to angularjs view

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I am making a simple chat app with angular on client side and sails on server side.on angular side i've used *ngResource* for server side connection.messages transport is done but the problem is whenever a new message is added to messages list which is shown by ng-repeat,it isn't shown on realtime in chatbox browser is needed to be refreshed.

According to my perception,it is because of including routing layer on client side instead of using ng-controller's directive in view file.but how to fix it because i need this routting layer too n realtime changes in view too.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To make a chat application with real time update, you have to use socket.
A useful tutorial is here: http://maangalabs.com/blog/2014/12/04/socket-in-sails/